# Interpretation of modulus of continuity of Brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, probability, continuity, brownian-motion

I am reading the book "Brownian Motion" by
Peter Morters and Yuval Peres. There I came across the notion of modulus of continuity of Brownian motion, defined as a random function $\phi: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{h\downarrow 0} \phi(h) =0$, $$\limsup_{h \downarrow 0}\ \sup_{0\leqslant t\leqslant1-h} \frac{|B(t+h)-B(t)|}{\phi(h)}\leqslant 1$$I can understand what that technically means, we look at the term $\sup_{0\leqslant t\leqslant1-h} \frac{|B(t+h)-B(t)|}{\phi(h)}$ as a function of $h$ and take the limit superior as $h\to 0$. But I am unable to get any intuition for that, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. $\phi$ is not a random function. 2. Have you looked at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy's_modulus_of_continuity_theorem) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) ?

Comment: @KurtG. The book defines $\phi$ to be a random function. And later it is shown (with Levy's modulus of continuity theorem) that a single $\phi$ works for all $\omega$.   Thank you for sharing the links, I went through the Wikipedia page before, but I will take a look again.

Comment: I am adding this comment to bump the question. I hope it is fine.